# Can't access the token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, auth0

I made an ASP.NET MVC (Framework 4.5.2) application that uses AUTH0 and it works well until I try to access the token, following its instructions.

In a given point it asks to add the following lines to the Startup.cs class:

```
if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
{
    notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", "https://quickstarts/api");
}
```

this lines added, in the exactly same spot the instructions says, whenever I access the application it gives me a message saying that the site can't be reached. If I take out those lines, it all works well.

What configuration do I need to correctly access the token?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: This one: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-owin